# javascript appendchild which does not inherit the css of parent

Tags: javascript, css

I have a need to insert special iconfont children nodes into a base document.

The character sequence that I need is 'fT', and I wrap this in a span to give it a color and size for that font that I want.

The problem is that the parent node of the base document which I am attaching this 'note' child to may sometimes have an uppercase style.  As a result, my 'fT' gets converted to 'FT', and I get the wrong iconfont.

My design doesn't want to insert a sibling into the document, but a child node.  Is there a way to inhibit the style of the parent, especially if it has uppercase style?

Comment: Than set the class of the element that sets the font the way you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to color and size, also set `text-transform: none` on the span so that the casing isn't inherited from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to set the style by JS - http://jsfiddle.net/RahV3/

```
yourNode.style.textTransform = "lowercase";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the child its own style to trump the parent's attribute. Just give it:

```
"text-transform:initial;"
```

and it should override the parent's

```
"text-transform:uppercase;"
```